# String ReplaceAll method not working

Tags: java, regex

I'm using this method to parse out plain text URLs in some HTML and make them links

```
private String fixLinks(String body) {
    String regex = "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
    body = body.replaceAll(regex, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
    Log.d(TAG, body);
    return body;
}
```

No URLs are replaced in the HTML however. The regular expression seems to be matching URLs in other regular expression testers. What's going on?

Comment: Can you post an example snippet of HTML? Are you sure the links are all at the beginning of the line? I'd add a `\s*` after the `^` to allow for whitespace.

Comment: +1 for asking a question about replaceAll that wasn't confusion about it expecting a regex :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `^` anchor means the regex can only match at the start of the string. Try removing it.

Also, it looks like you mean `$0` rather than `$1`, since you want the entire match and not the first capture group, which is `(https?|ftp|file)`.

In summary, the following works for me:

```
private String fixLinks(String body) {
    String regex = "(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
    body = body.replaceAll(regex, "<a href=\"$0\">$0</a>");
    Log.d(TAG, body);
    return body;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. You just saved me from jumping off a bridge.